# Linux : How to set up "global" user / passwords / groups file in svn

Tags: linux, svn, configuration, passwd, authz

I'm trying to set up global user / group access to all my svn repositories on Linux. Since I am very new to svn / linux stuff can someone take a look at what I have set up. I still get a "Invalid authz configuration". Here is how I proceed :

---

Svn installed / properly working. Serving path `home/svn/repos/`.

"my_project" created, works using simple auth. Path is `home/svn/repos/my_project/`.

My "global" user / password + groups file `/home/svn/passwd`

```
[groups]
team_a = tom, sim
team_b = jake, roy
prod = frank
[users]
tom = j9uems
sim = 90uifs
jake = fd9j8p
roy = 8ujwek
frank = 8jfjel
```

My configuration file `home/svn/repos/my_project/conf/svnserve.conf`

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = /home/svn/passwd
authz-db = authz
```

My authorization file `home/svn/repos/my_project/conf/authz`

```
[/]
# this project is a team_a project. But jake can have a read acces to it
@team_a = rw
@team_b =
jake = r
@prod = r
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok I Found out a better way to set up a global authentifications / access. If that info could help...

To remove or create a new user, I used a a global "passwd" file (**no groups!**) `/home/svn/passwd`

```
[users]
tom = j9uems
sim = 90uifs
jake = fd9j8p
roy = 8ujwek
frank = 8jfjel
```

To manage groups and global access to repositories on the server, I used a global "authz" file `/home/svn/authz`

```
[groups]
team_a = tom, sim
team_b = jake, roy
prod = frank

[my_project:/]
# access denied for everyone
* =
@team_a = rw
jake = r
@prod = r
```

All repositories must have **the same svnserve.conf** `home/svn/repos/my_project/conf/svnserve.conf`

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = /home/svn/passwd
authz-db = /home/svn/authz
```

---

Note that access may be granted to any groups / users to any path of any repos. For example if "prod" group needs to have full access to "production" folder of that project, that is possible :

```
[my_project:/production]
@prod = rw
```